# C++ Object changing is address during execution

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am working on C++ in Win7. The scenario is as follows:

Object --> binary serialization --> binary de-serialization --> Object

For serialization and deserialization we are using boost.

The de-serialization is successful. But when we start calling its function execute(), after the execution of first line all its data got corrupted. It's noted in local variables tab that the "this" address gets changed automatically.

After entering in the function
[image: After entering in the function]

After executing first line of function
[image: After executing first line of function]

Here is the source code

```
  void NewFrameCommand::execute()
    {
        FrameStructure st = getStructure();

        setState(InExecution, S_OK, "Executing NewFrameCommand ...");
        unsigned long errorcode;
        SharedMemoryFrame* sharedFrame = getSharedFrame(errorcode);
        if (sharedFrame == nullptr)
        {       
            return;
        }

        Frame* grayScaleframe = sharedFrame->frame();
...
    }
```

The serialization code from header file

```
class LPRCOMMANDS_API NewFrameCommand : public LPRCommandBase
        {
            friend class boost::serialization::access;
            template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::base_object<LPRCommandBase>(*this);              
            }

        public:
            NewFrameCommand();
            ~NewFrameCommand();

            NewFrameCommand(const const FrameStructure& aGrayScaleStructure, const char* aGrayScaleMemoryName);

        public: //CommandBase implementation
            int id() const;
            virtual void execute();
            virtual void deserialize(const char* aData, const int aDataLength);
            virtual void serialize(char** aData, int& aLength) const;
        };
```

and Base Class

```
class LPRCOMMANDS_API LPRCommandBase : public Commands::CommandBase
        {
            friend class boost::serialization::access;
            template <class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::base_object<CommandBase>(*this);
                ar & m_MemoryName;
                ar & m_Structure;
            }
...
}
```

Any idea how this can happen and how can it be fixed.

Regards,
Jawad.

Comment: show some code, not only screenshots. Probably (if your observations are correct) something bad happens in functions called from current one

Comment: It could depend on the data you sent through the wire (serialization). If it contains addresses, you need to send the referenced instances too. If the deserialized object is on the stack or a reference, it get destroyed when a new function is acalled which modifies the stack. Check the lifetime of your deserialized objects. Check where they are (stack/heap).

Comment: Have you tried stepping into `getStructure`? Also, is this compiled with optimizations?

Comment: Make a SSCCE. See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Comment: 1) Do you see `this` changing just in a debugger or you have some other symtomps of `this` change? A highly optimized code may cache vital data (like `this`) in register, while the debugger prints the stack. 2) If it;s actual corruption of `this` on a stack, possibly there's a buffer overflow in `getStructure()` or in `setState()`. You should trace them to see what happens inside.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in `getStructure()` and `setState()`. `getStructure()` simply returns the `FrameStructure` as value and even after `this` corruption, the `st` retains its value. And `setState()` sets the State and prints on console. 
I commented both statements and then even `this` got corrupted on calling `getSharedFrame()`. Earlier `this` was corrupting even before the code pointer gets inside `getSharedFrame()` and now on executing `getSharedFrame()` it still corrupts `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found an issue, however, I still don't know why it still happens..
The `deserialize()` function was causing an issue.

```
void NewFrameCommand::deserialize(const char* aData, const int aDataLength)
{
    //NewFrameCommand* temp = static_cast<NewFrameCommand *>(static_cast<void*>(const_cast<char*>(aData)));
    //*this = *temp; //copying data
    stringstream data;
    data.write(const_cast<char*>(aData), aDataLength);

    assert(aDataLength == data.str().size());

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(data);
    ia >> *this;

    data.clear();
}
```

When `data.clear()` is commented out, it starts working fine. Even though `data` is created on stack and eventually it has to be destroyed, the call to `clear()` shouldn't make any issue, since `ia >> *this;` copied data to `this` already.

Now the question is, `stringstream::clear()` only sets the `state` of stream, how it really changes the data. And if it changes its own data, how come it changes the data of some other object `this`.